# find first parent by tag of ng-click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

How can I use $event to find the parent `tr` element using only jqLite?

here is an example of the click event handler/problem:

```
<td ng-click="showDataClick($event)"><i></i></td>
```

Here is my template:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="record in filteredData = (state.filteredRecords | orderBy : state.sort.column : state.sort.descending | pagination : state.settings.currentPage : state.settings.recordsPerPage)" class="table-row" audit-row record="record">
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="filteredData.length === 0" class="table-row">
        <td colspan="5" class="text-center">No records found</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: does this tr are rendered using `ng-repeat`?

Comment: What's the overall goal? And why not `.parent()`?

Comment: @tymeJV he want tr just above it not..parent will give `tr` element of tr..

Comment: @tyme JV yeah the thing is sometimes I get the `<i>` tag from `$event.target` and so using `.parent()` wouldn't work in all cases...

Comment: @pankajparkar yes it was created using ng-repeat

Comment: @Timigen what you are going to do with parent element.

Comment: @pankajparkar I want to append another 'tr' tag after it in the table...

Comment: @Timigen please add whole code..i Can't see `ng-repeat` code in you question

Comment: @pankajparkar ng-repeat snippet added!

Answer (score 0):

After reading your entire question here is a working demo of inserting a row after the clicked row [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrcag8j/4/)

html

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td ng-click="showDataClick($event)"><i>Nested Element</i> no nesting element       </td>
         <td ng-click="showDataClick($event)">
           Multiple td's
         </td>
         <td ng-click="showDataClick($event)">
             <div>
                 <div>
                     nested in multiple elements
                 </div>
             </div>
         </td>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-click="showDataClick($event)"><i>row 1</i>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-click="showDataClick($event)"><i>row 2</i>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.showDataClick = function (e) {
        var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
        newRow.innerHTML = '<td>Hey There I am new</td>';
        var sibling = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
        var next = sibling.nextSibling;
        var parent = sibling.parentElement;
        parent.insertBefore(newRow, next);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this would fail, in my use case for one the icon is only filling up so much of the `td`.  This means sometimes i need to go up 2 elements to `tr` tag and sometimes if i click on the just th `td` 1 element...

Comment: This is just meant to show the example of going up the chain from the event. If you really want to get just the tr why not move the clickhandler to the tr element then you will know the srcElement is always the row. Do you have a specific reason for not wanting to do that?

Comment: Oh I thought this was an answer...And yes there is a reason the `ng-click` is where it is.  Not that that would solve the issue anyway...as I said above